# Convert column values into rows in the order in which columns are present

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Below is a sample dataframe I have. I need to convert each row into multiple rows based on month.

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'Jan': [100,200,300],
                   'Feb': [400,500,600],
                   'March':[700,800,900],
                   })
```

**Desired output :**

`Jan   100
Feb   400
March 700
Jan   200
Feb   500
March 800
Jan   300
Feb   600
March 900`

Tried using pandas melt function but what it does is it will group Jan together, then Feb and March. It will be like 3 rows for Jan, then 3 for Feb and same for March. But i want to achieve the above output. Could someone please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with some data cleaning by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = (df.stack()
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
        .rename_axis('months')
        .reset_index(name='val'))
```

Or use `numpy` - flatten values and repeat columns names by [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'months': np.tile(df.columns, len(df)),
                    'val': df.values.reshape(1,-1).ravel()})
```

---

```
print (df1)
  months  val
0    Jan  100
1    Feb  400
2  March  700
3    Jan  200
4    Feb  500
5  March  800
6    Jan  300
7    Feb  600
8  March  900
```

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what i needed. :)